# Flink S3 StreamingFileSink not writing files to S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-flink

I am doing a POC for writing data to S3 using Flink. The program does not give a error. However I do not see any files being written in S3 either.

Below is the code

```java
public class StreamingJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // set up the streaming execution environment
        final String outputPath = "s3a://testbucket-s3-flink/data/";
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        
        //Enable checkpointing
        env.enableCheckpointing();
        //S3 Sink
        final StreamingFileSink<String> sink = StreamingFileSink
                .forRowFormat(new Path(outputPath), new SimpleStringEncoder<String>("UTF-8"))
                .build();


        //Source is a local kafka
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9094");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");
        

        DataStream<String> input = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>("queueing.transactions", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));
        
        
        input.flatMap(new Tokenizer()) // Tokenizer for generating words
                .keyBy(0) // Logically partition the stream for each word
                .timeWindow(Time.minutes(1)) // Tumbling window definition
                .sum(1) // Sum the number of words per partition
                .map(value -> value.f0 + " count: " + value.f1.toString() + "\n")
                .addSink(sink);

        // execute program
        env.execute("Flink Streaming Java API Skeleton");
    }

    public static final class Tokenizer
            implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {

        @Override
        public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) {
            String[] tokens = value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");
            for (String token : tokens) {
                if (token.length() > 0) {
                    out.collect(new Tuple2<>(token, 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I have set the `s3.access-key` and `s3.secret-key` value in the configuration and tested by changing them to incorrect values (I got a error on incorrect values)

Any pointers what may be going wrong?

Comment: Have you included the flink-s3-fs-hadoop dependency? This is necessary.

Comment: It is enabled as a plug-in using the ENABLE_PLUGINS environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are running into [this issue](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html#general)?

> Given that Flink sinks and UDFs in general do not differentiate between normal job termination (e.g. finite input stream) and termination due to failure, upon normal termination of a job, the last in-progress files will not be transitioned to the “finished” state.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. However it was silly issue in my flatmap.